# Applying any operator to two integers (in python)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that takes any operator and applies it to two integers. Any thoughts?

for example:

> > > apply_operator("+", 40, 5)
> > >       45
> > >       apply_operator("-", 40, 5)
> > >       35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a mapping of operators to attributes of `operator`, and then have the function get the entry in the map and apply it to the operands.